# Can you increase the maximum automatic open size?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using sql-developer to export just the DDl of an oracle database with 3 schema's in it.

The export ran for approx 12 hours, then popped up a message stating

`File export.sql was not opened because it exceeds the maximum automatic open size`

I've got 2 questions really

1. Has the export finished at this point?
2. If it hasn't, is there a way to increase the maximum automatic open size?

I haven't used sql developer to export a DDL before, so not sure if this is just the tool trying to open the file after the successful export.

Amny tips or help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the file is there on your disk, where you told us to put it.

There's no way to increase this limit.

You can open the file if you want to, but I'd caution against this if the file is very large...if you want to execute it, use the @file.sql notation.

If you want to browse it, use tail or head.